# Variable does not exist (using startsWith)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lookup

With this code, I try to check the two conditions of the size of the list and the field MyFamily__c which must not be null, and it works correctly, now I added the very first condition which consists in checking if the field Code__c starts with the value AB, this field exists on the Account object which has lookup with ObjInfo__c but I get this error:

```
Variable does not exist: Account__r
```

This is my code

```
public static boolean checkObj(Id Accountid){
            List<ObjInfo__c> ListInfo = [SELECT id, MyFamily__c, Account__r.Code__c FROM ObjInfo__c WHERE Account__r.id =:Accountid  ];      
     
             if(ListInfo.Account__r.Code__c.startsWith('AB') )
             {
                    if(ListInfo.size() == 0 ){
                 return false;
             }
             else{
                for(ObjInfo__c info: ListInfo) {
                    if(info.MyFamily__c == null){
                        return false;
                    }
                 }  
               
             }
             }
               return true;
         
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListInfo` is a list of records. You need to access a specific record (e.g. index 0):

```
if(ListInfo[0].Account__r.Code__c.startsWith('AB') )
```

Your logic is out of order, you should first check if the list is empty, and if not, then check for the other conditions.

Comment: thank you  for your help .